# How to merge multiple JSON objects in MySql

Tags: mysql

We are using MySql 5.7.12 version

I'm trying to merge multiple JSON objects into a single JSON object single object and want to remove quotes for integer fields

```
select JSON_OBJECT(count(1), status) from table_name where status in ('X','Y','Z') group by status;
```

results I'm getting

```
+------------------------------+
| JSON_OBJECT(status,count(1)) |
+------------------------------+
| {"X": 6}                     |
| {"Y": 93}                    |
| {"Z": 75}                    |
+------------------------------+
```

I want results like following

```
{"X":6,"Y":93,"Z":75}
```

I tried to wrap above query with `json_merge` function but I didn't get the expected result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL version `5.7.22` or later, then there is a JSON function called [`JSON_OBJECTAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg) which should work here:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(status, cnt)
FROM 
(
    SELECT status, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY status
) t;
```

This assumes that you want to JSON aggregate over the entire table.

Comment: hmm we are using 5.7.12 version

Comment: @Rams Then it might not be possible to do this.  Well, there might be some hackish way to do it.  Or, you could handle this problem in an app language like Java or C# where powerful JSON functions are cheap and easy to come by.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, which just post-processes your existing query:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(a.x, '}', ''), '{', '')
        SEPARATOR ','
    )
FROM (
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(count(1), status) AS x FROM table_name where status in ('X','Y','Z') GROUP BY status) 
) AS a
```